# Send email from mercury to GMail

Tags: php, email

I have a Mercury SMTP server running on localhost (announcing as 127.0.0.1) right now.

Unfortunately, I am unable to send emails from it to GMail.

I tested sending an email to myself using localhost and PHP, and viewed the result in Outlook.

I received both an email and an error message that the email could not be sent.

In Mercury, the only settings I have changed are add the working user to the user-list and set up the SMTP server to announce as 127.0.0.1 (My from is set to @127.0.0.1). Port is 25.

I'm using SwiftMailer to connect (and I know the code works because I could connect to my GMail account).

When I paste the errors with

```
if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
        {
          echo "Failures:";
          print_r($failures);
        }
```

I get something like Failures:Array( [0]=>'@gmail.com')

What could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried something OTHER than gmail? don't assume that this is a php problem - if mercury isn't configured correctly, **ANY** outbound email may not be working.

Comment: That's what I think the problem is, is there anything specific I need to do to configure outgoing messages in MErcury? My user has admin privileges

Comment: no idea. and that's not really programming anymore. that gets into server configuration.

Comment: Should I migrate to server fault?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, I had to change SMTP settings to allow outgoing mails.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1231284) is where I got the answer for anyone else having the same problem